# Form handling in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to set the value in my input text using the get method. However, when I try to render the page, it keep showing my code in the text field instead. Can someone explain what I did wrong?

```
<form name="quotepage" action="search.php" method="get">
    <b>Stock Symbol:</b>
    <input type="text" size="8" name="sb" value="<?php echo $_GET["sb"]; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Quote" onClick="quotepage.action='search.php';"/>
</form>
```

When I try to render the page, it will show my code in the value tag in my text field.

Comment: what kind of code will it show? An error/warning, or do you see litterally `<?php echo.....` ?

Comment: Is your page a php file or HTML?

Comment: Are you runnig the code server side? Is the name ending with .php?

Comment: I literally see <?php echo ...? Is it because I have to run it on the server in order for it to run probably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeing an error/warning/notice in your text box, try changing:

```
<?php echo $_GET["sb"]; ?>
```

into:

```
<?php echo isset($_GET["sb"])?$_GET["sb"]:""; ?>
```

to avoid showing the content if there was no content yet.

And better yet, change it to:

```
<?php echo isset($_GET["sb"])?htmlspecialchars($_GET["sb"]):""; ?>
```

to also escape nasty characters such as `"` that otherwise will break your HTML.

---

If you are actually seeing  `<?php echo $_GET["sb"]; ?>` inside your text box, then you are having problems running PHP. Check that your script file name ends with `.php` and check PHP is working on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a LAMP stack or similar set up?
You need Apache running with PHP installed at the least for this. Also what is this 'onClick="quotepage.action='search.php';"' attribute for?